# SFTP fatal bad ownership or modes for chroot directory ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, chroot

I just set up my SFTP server and it works fine when I use it from my first user account.
I wanted to add a user which we will call 'magnarp'.
At first I did like this in sshd_config:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp


Match group sftponly
    ChrootDirectory /home/%u
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

That worked fine enough, user magnarp went into his home directory.
I then tried to add a symbolic link to it.

```
home$ sudo ln -s /home/DUMP/High\ Defenition/ /home/magnarp/"High Defenition"
```

The symlink worked fine via SSH but not over SFTP.

So what I want to do now is to Chroot group sftponly to /home/DUMP
and i did like this:

```
Match group sftponly
    ChrootDirectory /home/DUMP
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

The DUMP folder have permissions as follows.

```
drwxrwxrwx  5 root     root      4096 aug 18 02:25 DUMP
```

And this is the error code:

```
Aug 18 16:40:29 nixon-01 sshd[7346]: Connection from 192.168.1.198 port 51354
Aug 18 16:40:30 nixon-01 sshd[7346]: Accepted password for magnarp from 192.168.1.198 port 51354 ssh2
Aug 18 16:40:30 nixon-01 sshd[7346]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user    magnarp by (uid=0)
Aug 18 16:40:30 nixon-01 sshd[7346]: User child is on pid 7467
Aug 18 16:40:30 nixon-01 sshd[7467]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/home/DUMP"
Aug 18 16:40:30 nixon-01 sshd[7346]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user magnarp
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`sshd` has a certain level of paranoia when it comes to chroot directories. I do not think this can be disabled (even with `StrictModes no`).  The chroot directory and all parent directories must [be properly set](http://takahisa.info/2010/03/18/sftp-chroot-with-openssh-error-fatal-bad-ownership-or-modes-for-chroot-directory/):

1. The chroot directory and all of its parents must not have group or world write capabilities (ie `chmod 755`)
2. The chroot directory and all of its parents must be owned by root.

In your case the login error can be fixed with `chmod 755 /home/DUMP`  Your apparent intent to have a world-writable directory that sftpuser can log into and everyone can put files in can be solved by making that directory a subdirectory of `/home/DUMP/`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you. Now I just have to fix all the sub-directories and my NFS system as well :)

Answer (score 0):

A) What would be the point of making chroot if making simlinks would help evading the chroot? (Any user could upload a simlink and then get access to the whole filesystem)

B) One more chmod 777 and you will get flammed by theo (http://rlv.zcache.com/i_got_flamed_by_theo_de_raadt_t_shirt_tshirt-p235453348828729121en7rf_210.jpg). See http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2010-January/028151.html to understand why openssh is so picky about chroot directory permissions.